# Spring Ajax/Json User Update Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, jsp

Basically so far, I have a JSP page where the administrator can view all the current registered users in a simple table. The administrator can then update User information(authority, email, etc) when the specific table row 'update' button is clicked.

I would like to know how I can make a pop up modal appear on the screen with a form and the current user information displayed in it, rather then redirecting it to another page and shopping a form. Are there any good tutorials which show how to implement this type of functionality?

I am building this web application based on the Spring framework.
This is my JSP page so far.. For testing I just made a button named Ajax Testing, although really I want my 'update' button to instantiate a modal and load user information.

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${user.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.username}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.dob}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.authority}"/></td>
            <td>
                <a id="update" href="<c:url value="/viewUser"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>"><button>Update</button></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="delete" href="<c:url value="/deleteUser"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>"><button>Delete</button></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="loadUser" href="<c:url value="/ajaxTest"><c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/></c:url>"><button>Ajax Test</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
 <div id="personIdResponse"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loadUser").click(function(){
            var personId = +$('#loadUser').val();
            $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SDP_v1.2_JSON_TEST/ajaxTest/' + personId, function(user) {
                  $('#personIdResponse').text(user.name + ', = username ' + user.username);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewUser")
public String updateUser(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) {

    User user = usersService.getUser(id);

    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "settings";
}

@RequestMapping("/ajaxTest")
@ResponseBody
public User ajaxTest(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) {
    return usersService.getUser(id);
}

@RequestMapping("/updateUser")
public String updateUser(Model model, User user) {

    usersService.updateUser(user);
    getUsers(model);
    return "users";
}

@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
public String deleteUser(Model model,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) {

    if (id == null) {
        List<User> users = usersService.getUsers();

        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "users";
    } else {
        usersService.delete(id);

        List<User> users = usersService.getUsers();

        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "users";
    }

}
```

I cannot get anything in the set text displayed in the

Comment: You might just instead try it yourself and then post your code here. Stack Overflow's Q&A model doesn't really scale as a search tool. Did you try Googling?  If so, include what you found in your post. What did you find and why didn't that answer your question?

Comment: I am stuck on actually where to start, whether to use JSON or AJAX? or both.

Comment: JSON is JavaScript object notation. It's just a wrapper, whereas AJAX is a technique that generally uses XML but could use JSON instead. Since JavaScript parses JSON by default, JSON would likely be the better answer.  It sounds like you just need a RESTful URL you can hit via jQuery AJAX to get the data in JSON format so that you can then use a jQuery modal plugin to build the window, then simply parse the JSON and populate it. If you start with that, you'll likely get stuck. When you do, you should edit this post with your progress. Right now, this is way too broad to answer. Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great answer! I will give it a shot an see how I go from there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider jQueryUI dialog form. See examples [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

Your HTML would be:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="user update">
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    ... some other properties
    </fieldset>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Your javascript:

```
$("btn.update")
  .click(function() {
    $("input#name").val('the name of the user'); // you should be able to retrieve the info or id based on the row. Use changed selectors like closest("tr").find("td").eq(2)...
    $("#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
```

---

UPDATE:

I noticed more code has been posted in the question.

First issue, you really should not give `id` to the update, delete hyperlinks. Since they are repeated in a number of rows, you will have DOM elements with duplicated `id`. So, please consider using `class`.

Then, here is how you populate the dialog form with the data from server.

```
$(".loadUser").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // to cancel the default hyperlink behavior.
        var personId = +$(this).val(); // obtain the user Id.
        $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SDP_v1.2_JSON_TEST/ajaxTest/' + personId)
             .done(function(user) {
                  // populate the dialog form with data retrieved.
                  $("input#name").val(user.username); 
                  ...

                  // display the dialog form
                  $("#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
              })
              .fail(function(user) {
                  alert('could not load user');
              });
    });
```

Comment: This is great, and pretty much exactly what I am looking for! The only thing I dont clearly understand, is how do I load each individual user information into the form when it pop's up. At the moment, when an `update` button is clicked, it gets processed a controller, then gets dispatched to another page where the form is displayed.

Comment: In adddition to this, you could modify your views for things like "users" in JSON format, and then in your success callback you can do stuff with that data. For instance, a JSON "user" you get from the server could go where Blaise put 'the name of the user'.

Comment: Yeah I keep trying things, although I cannot seem to get it working. Very Irritating.

Comment: I noticed you have posted more info in the question, please see the updated answer.